# Can't get Flatlist pull to refresh working

Tags: javascript, react-native

The docs are pretty straight forward but somehow I can not get the pull to refresh working. The data is loaded correctly at the `componentDidMount` but `_refresh`is not called when I try to pull down the list. I tried it on a iPhone and Android device. On Android I can't even pull down the list (no rubber effect).

Here is my code:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null };
  state = { data: [], isLoading: true };

  _fetchData = async () => {
    const data = [];
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');
      const responseJSON = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data: responseJSON.results, isLoading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      alert('some error');
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
  };

  _refresh = () => {
    alert('this is never be shown');
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this._fetchData();
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this._fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading)
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="darkorange" />
        </View>
      );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.email}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <FriendListItem
              friend={item}
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate('FriendsScreen', {
                  friend: item,
                })
              }
            />
          )}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.listSeparator} />}
          ListEmptyComponent={() => <Text>empty</Text>}
          onRefresh={this._refresh}
          refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double check your FlatList import. I'm pretty sure that you imported FlatList from react-native-gesture-handler. If yes then remove it.

FlatList should be imported from react-native like below.

**import { FlatList } from 'react-native';**

If above is not the case then share with me your StyleSheet.

Let me know if it helps.